# truncate by doing "string" + 1 in C

Tags: c, char, truncate

I recently came across the following code on stack overflow ([see the whole post here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4319763/how-do-i-remove-the-first-number-from-an-integer)):-

```
char *c = "200939915";
char *d = c + 1;
```

It assigns d a value of "00939915", which I find very counter-intuitive.

Can someone explain the mechanism of the process?
 What is this thing called?

I am a freshman and doing Introductory CS courses, so this would be of great help:)

Comment: What does your course textbook say? What did a Google search reveal? These questions have been answered before, so you should be able to find the answer.

Comment: `d` is a pointer that points to the second character in the array pointed to by `c` (`c[1]`), whereas `c` points to the first element (`c[0]`). So if you print `d`, naturally it'll start from the second character

Comment: @AntonH I tried finding it on stackoverflow, but  have no idea what to search (ie. its name).

Comment: @aditya You're know you're working with pointers, and you're adding a value. I literally entered "pointer add" in Google. It auto-completed to "pointer addition", and resulted in many responses for "pointer addition" and "pointer arithmetic". Less than 30 seconds to find a slew of help directly on Google.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
char *c = "200939915";
```

Here `c` is a pointer to a char(The first char of `200939915`).
`c+1` will point to the next char.

```
          (2 0 0 9 3 9 9 1 5)
           ^ ^
           | |
           c c+1
```

Comment: Thanks dude. I did CS50 this summer and your answer just helped me connect the dots :p

Comment: @aditya Maybe because i have taken CS50 too.Glad i could help.

Answer (score 2):

`d` does not "contain" the value you said.
`d` is a pointer to a `char` and by setting it to `c+1` it points (contains the memory address) to the second element of the string literal you declared.

I guess you did something like this `printf("%s",d);` this leads to printf reading the memory starting from the position `d` points to and output every character in there until it catches a `'\0'` (end of string) and then finish.

It does not truncate your string you just start reading it at another position.

Answer (score 1):

c[0] = 2
c[1] = 0
c[2] = 0
c[3] = 9
and so on.
`c` is the address of that first character, `2`.  So `d` is the address `c` + 1 more, therefore the address of the first `0` in this case.

Answer (score 1):

As @Gaurav Sehgal pointed out, your variables only point to strings of characters, not numbers. What would you expect the value of d to be here:

```
 char *c = "abcdefghi";
 char *d = c + 1;
```